# Replacing '\'' with sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

I want to replace `'\''` in a text file to another word or character using `sed` command.

Tried using `sed "s/'\''/×/g"` but it doesn't work.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to replace the literal text `'\''` you would need

```
sed "s/'\\\\''/new text/g"
```

The `\` needs to be escaped as `\\` to represent itself in a regular expression, then you have to double up each of those backslashes since they are part of a double quoted string.  You need to use a double quoted string since you want to match single quotes (and a single quoted string can't contain single quotes).

Alternatively:

```
sed "s/'[\\]''/new text/g"
```

Where `[\\]` would be converted to `[\]` due to the double-quoting of the string before it's given to `sed`.  A backslash in a bracketed expression in a regular expression is always literal.

---

Your command

```
sed "s/'\''/×/g"
```

is functionally the same as

```
sed "s/'''/×/g"
```

and will replace any triple single quote with the character `×`.